# Apply a condition only once in a recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I want to apply a condition inside a resursion only once. My data structure looks as follows

```
stages = {"stage_1": False, "stage_2":False, "stage_3":False,"state_4": False}
```

I want to pick any stage randomly from it and change the status to True. But when total number of true stage is 3 I want to randomly change a True stage to False. But only once. Then it should continue to turn stages in to True. When all 4 stages are true. The recursion process stops.
How can I do that ?
I have tried the following code. but it is not complete.

```
def process(stages):
    all_stages = [stage for stage, status in stages.items() if status == False]
    if len(all_stages) !=0:
        print(all_stages)
        select_ = random.choice(all_stages)
        print("\tselected stage: ",select_)
        
        stages[select_] = True
        process(stages)
    else:
        print("Done")
        print(stages)

process(stages)
```

This works without adding that extra condition. I have tried the following one. But that does not work

```
def process(stages):
    all_stages = [stage for stage, status in stages.items() if status == False]
    if len(all_stages) !=0:
        print(all_stages)
        select_ = random.choice(all_stages)
        print("\tselected stage: ",select_)
        
        stages[select_] = True

        if len(all_stages) == 1:
            select_ = random.choice([stage for stage, status in stages.items() if status == True])
            stages[select_] = False
        process(stages)
    else:
        print("Done")
        print(stages)

process(stages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code is the suggestion from @NoBlockhit

```
stages = {"stage_1": False, "stage_2":False, "stage_3":False,"state_4": False}

status = True
def process(stages):
    global status
    print(status)
    all_stages = [stage for stage, status in stages.items() if status == False]
    if len(all_stages) !=0:
        print(all_stages)
        select_ = random.choice(all_stages)
        print("\tselected stage: ",select_)
        
        stages[select_] = True

        if status:
            if len(all_stages) == 1:
                select_ = random.choice([stage for stage, status in stages.items() if status == True])
                stages[select_] = False
                status = False
        process(stages)
    else:
        print("Done")
        print(stages)

process(stages)
```

Answer (score 2):

As with many recursion problems, adding a state to your function call will help you a lot.

Consider making an inner call to `process_internal()` that would get the current state of the recursion, whether it's stage 0 (False -> True), stage 1 (True -> False) or stage 2 (False -> True).

```
import random

def flip_random_state(stages, relevant_bool_val):
    [print(f"Stage: {key} with status {value}") for key, value in stages.items()]
    relevant_stages = [stage for stage, status in stages.items() if status == relevant_bool_val]
    selected_stage = random.choice(relevant_stages)
    print(f"\tSelected stage: {selected_stage}\n")
    stages[selected_stage] = not stages[selected_stage]
    return stages

def count_stages_with_status(stages, input_status):
    return len([stage for stage, status in stages.items() if status == input_status])

def process_internal(stages, state):
    print(f"State: {state}")
    if state == 2 and count_stages_with_status(stages, True) == 4:
        print("Done")
        print(stages)
        return
    
    if state == 0 or state == 2:
        relevant_bool_val = False
    else:
        relevant_bool_val = True

    if state == 1 and count_stages_with_status(stages, False) == 4:
        state = 2
        return process_internal(stages, state)
    
    if state == 0 and count_stages_with_status(stages, True) == 3:
        state = 1
        return process_internal(stages, state)

    stages = flip_random_state(stages, relevant_bool_val)

    return process_internal(stages, state)

def process(stages):
    return process_internal(stages, 0)

stages = {"stage_1": False, "stage_2": False, "stage_3": False,"state_4": False}
process(stages)
```

Comment: Could you please help me with an example ? I have tried similer approch but the problem is the situation with 3 true stages are occuring again. Then this function gets stuck

Comment: The code is quite verbose, but hopefully, the addition of 'states' clarifies what's happening at every step.

Comment: small remark though: with this code the state changes after the making the everything true, which is wrong. if the all of stages are true then the process ends. it should be done before reaching to `all state true` status

Comment: You are correct, I've made some mistakes. Recursion is always a bit tricky. In any case, I hope this gave you a better sense of the usage of states in recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a global variable as a flag to get, wheather you already set one back to False, or add an optional parameter like returnedToFalse=False
And set it to true when you eventually set one to false already.

Comment: with code example please

Comment: I am on my phone atm sorry. That would take a while.

Comment: I think this approach is the better one. I have tried one which is  working